# Eclipse error while using setBackgroundDrawable on an ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview, drawable, setbackground

When using the setBackgroundDrawable method on an ImageView, Eclipse gives the following error:
"The method setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (int)"
My ImageView is defined in xml as:

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCheck1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/box"
                android:contentDescription=" " />
```

Defined and implemented in java as:

```
public class QuizList extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageView check1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.theView);
    IntializeVariables();
    IntializeChecks()
}

private void IntializeVariables() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    check1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivCheck1);

}

private void IntializeChecks() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean check = getPrefs.getBoolean("quiz1pref", false);
    if (check == true) {
        check1.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.check);
    }
}
```

Anyone got any idea why it's giving this error, or how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
check1.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.check);
```

This is the error. Please change it to

```
check1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check);
```

or

```
check1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
check1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :-

```
check1.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.check);
```

Use this :-

```
check1.setImageResource(R.drawable.check);
```

Comment: Whenever you're using code in your answer or comment, enclose it with the code tag so that the code appears formatted. That's what I edited.